# ¿Cómo puedo buscar la posición de una estructura mediante su valor en c++?

Tags: c++

He creado una estructura en `c++` en la que se encuentra un array. Lo que quiero hacer es pedir datos de canciones y que luego el usuario mediante el título de la canción, el autor o el género encuentre el array correspondiente y lo imprima en pantalla, pero no sé como hacer que busque dentro de la estructura el valor que coincida.
Gracias.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    struct datosCanciones{
        string nombre;
        string autor;
        string genero;
        short anno;
    };
    datosCanciones canciones [30];
    int n, t;

    cout<<"¿Cuántas canciones quieres añadir? "<<endl;  
    cin>> n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Introduce el nombre de la canción "<<i+1<<endl;  
        cin>> canciones[i].nombre;
        cout<<"Introduce su autor: "<<endl;
        cin>> canciones[i].autor;
        cout<<"Introduce su género: "<<endl;
        cin>> canciones[i].genero;
        cout<<"Introduce su fecha de publicación: "<<endl;
        cin>> canciones[i].anno;
    }

    cout<<"¿Qué canción quieres ver? "<<endl;   
    cin>> t;
    cout<<"Nombre "<<canciones[t-1].nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Autor: "<<canciones[t-1].autor<<endl;
    cout<<"Género: "<<canciones[t-1].genero<<endl;
    cout<<"Año: "<<canciones[t-1].anno<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la función [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) combinado con una lambda de búsqueda:

```
std::string nombre;
std::cout << "Buscar por nombre: ";
std::getline(std::cin, nombre);

auto entrada = std::find_if(std::begin(canciones), std::end(canciones),
    [&](const datosCanciones &dc)
    {
        return dc.nombre == nombre;
    });
```

Si `canciones` contiene un `datosCanciones` cuyo `datosCanciones::nombre` es el introducido por teclado, entonces `entrada` apuntará a ese elemento, en caso contrario apuntará a `std::end(canciones)`, así podrías comprobarlo:

```
if (entrada == std::end(canciones))
    std::cout << "La cancion " << nombre << " no esta registrada\n";
```

Necesitarás una lambda diferente por cada campo de búsqueda, lo cuál es bastante incómodo, yo optaría por una función plantilla:

```
template <typename CAMPO, typename TIPO, std::size_t ELEMENTOS>
auto busca(CAMPO campo, TIPO valor, const datosCanciones (&canciones)[ELEMENTOS])
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(canciones), std::end(canciones),
        [&](const datosCanciones &dc)
        {
            return (dc.*campo) == valor;
        });
}
```

La plantilla anterior recibe como primer parámetro el campo de la estructura en que quieres buscar, seguido del valor a buscar y acabando con la formación<sup>1</sup> en la que buscar, puede ser usada así:

```
auto ironmaiden = busca(&datosCanciones::autor, "Iron Maiden", canciones);
auto los80 = busca(&datosCanciones::anno, 1980, canciones);
```

La variable `ironmaiden` contendrá la primera entrada de `canciones` cuyo `datosCanciones::autor` sea `"Iron Maiden"`, la variable `los80` contendrá la primera entrada de `canciones` cuyo `datosCanciones::anno` sea `1980`.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o1ExegzoDZEy1WXp).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí un ejemplo de como buscar por los diferentes parámetros a excepción de la Fecha de Publicación que es de tipo short:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    struct datosCanciones{
        string nombre;
        string autor;
        string genero;
        short anno;
    };
    datosCanciones canciones [30];
    int n, t, numeroCancion;
    string dato;

    cout<<"¿Cuántas canciones quieres añadir? "<<endl;  
    cin>> n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Introduce el nombre de la canción "<<i+1<<endl;  
        cin>> canciones[i].nombre;
        cout<<"Introduce su autor: "<<endl;
        cin>> canciones[i].autor;
        cout<<"Introduce su género: "<<endl;
        cin>> canciones[i].genero;
        cout<<"Introduce su fecha de publicación: "<<endl;
        cin>> canciones[i].anno;
    }

    //SE SELECCIONA ALGUNO DE LOS ATRIBUTOS
    cout<<"¿Con qué información quieres buscar tu canción? "<<endl;   
    cout<<"1.Nombre Canción"<<endl;   
    cout<<"2.Autor"<<endl;  
    cout<<"3.Género"<<endl;  
    cout<<"4.Fecha de Públicación"<<endl; 
    cin>> t;

    cout<<"Ingrese el valor a buscar: "<<endl; 
    cin>> dato;

    // REALIZA LA BUSQUEDA POR Nombre Cancion/ Autor o Genero de acuerdo a lo anteriormente seleccionado
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        if(t == 1 ){
            if(canciones[t-1].nombre == dato){
                numeroCancion = t-1;
            }
        }else if(t == 2 ){
            if(canciones[t-1].autor == dato){
                numeroCancion = t-1;
            }
        }else if(t == 3 ){
            if(canciones[t-1].genero == dato){
                numeroCancion = t-1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Nombre "<<canciones[numeroCancion].nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Autor: "<<canciones[numeroCancion].autor<<endl;
    cout<<"Género: "<<canciones[numeroCancion].genero<<endl;
    cout<<"Año: "<<canciones[numeroCancion].anno<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Y Aquí un ejemplo con 2 canciones ingresadas y buscadas por autor queda lo siguiente:

```
¿Cuántas canciones quieres añadir? 
2

Introduce el nombre de la canción 1
SORRY
Introduce su autor: 
JUSTIN
Introduce su género: 
POP
Introduce su fecha de publicación: 
123

Introduce el nombre de la canción 2
PARADISE
Introduce su autor: 
GUNS
Introduce su género: 
ROCK
Introduce su fecha de publicación: 
123

¿Con qué información quieres buscar tu canción? 
1.Nombre Canción
2.Autor
3.Género
4.Fecha de Públicación
2

Ingrese el valor a buscar: 
GUNS

Nombre PARADISE
Autor: GUNS
Género: ROCK
Año: 123
```